# Lua HTTP request in ROBLOX is giving me a 403, but works on when testing in other places

Tags: javascript, heroku, proxy, lua, roblox

```
local httpService = game:GetService("HttpService");
local s = httpService:GetAsync("https://rbxapi.herokuapp.com/api/Users/1");
print(s);
```

This is a simple GET request that sends to my proxy server, but it continues to give me a 403 error.

> HTTP 403 (HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden)

When testing the URL on other sites like [API tester](https://apitester.com/), it works completely fine and passes the test.

The proxy server is hosted on heroku, which this is the code for the server:

```
const _express = require("express"),
      _proxy = require("express-http-proxy"),
      _fs = require("fs");
      _body_parser = require("body-parser")
var client = _express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000; 

client.use("/api", _proxy("https://api.roblox.com", {
    proxyReqPathResolver: function(req){
        return require('url').parse(req.url).path;
    },
}));

client.listen(port, (err) =>{
    if(err){
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log(`Server is now listenin' on port ${port}!`);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, ROBLOX knows that it originated from a game server, thus rejecting it.